# Pytorch "RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time" when increasing the dataset size mid model forward-pass

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to increase the dataset size within model forward passes. My (resnet) model has 6 layers and my dataset is split into batches. Each batch iteration, I forward pass the data through model's first 4 layers (model parameter `pass_part = 'first'`) and take the output. Then, I increase the size of that output by creating synthetic instances (method `mixup_data`) so that the `out` size increases from `batch_size` to 8*`batch_size`. After that, I split the resulting `out` into additional batches of `batch_size` and try to forward them through the last 2 layers my model (`pass_part = 'second'`). The second iteration of inner loop causes an error: `RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.`

What am I doing wrong? The code is below.

```
for batch_idx, (data, target, _) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = data.to(device)
        target_ohe = F.one_hot(target, args.num_classes)
        target_ohe = target_ohe.to(device)
                
        # Forward pass first part
        out = model(data, depth = args.depth, pass_part = 'first')
        # Mixup data
        out, target_ohe_full, _ = mixup_data.mixup_data(args.method, out, target_ohe, epoch, batch_idx, args.n_fraction, args.g_fraction, args.betaf_alpha, device)
        # Forward pass second part
        ### slice the resulting out into sizes of batch_size
        num_batch_mixup = int(np.ceil(out.shape[0]/args.batch_size))
        for batch_mixup_idx in range(num_batch_mixup):
            out_bm = out[args.batch_size*batch_mixup_idx : args.batch_size*(batch_mixup_idx+1)]
            output = model(out_bm, depth = args.depth, pass_part = 'second')
            target_ohe = target_ohe_full[args.batch_size*batch_mixup_idx : args.batch_size*(batch_mixup_idx+1)]
        
            loss = criterion(output, target_ohe)

            # Backward
            loss.backward()
            # Gradient clipping
            if args.grad_clip: 
                nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(parameters = model.parameters(), clip_value = args.grad_clip)
            # Optimize
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            scheduler.step()
```

Note that if the batch size is not increased (meaning the inner loop will only iterate once), the code works as expected. I do not understand why the error says it is making a second `.backward()` pass after only one `.forward()` pass if I cleary send each `out_bm` though the second part of my model, and calculate loss again (`loss = criterion(output, target_ohe)`).

Additionally, when setting `retain_graph` to `True` (even though I do not understand why that is necessary in my case) I get the following error: `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [512]], which is output 22 of BroadcastBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).` The [512] in my case is the number of filters of the `out` data.

Comment: by default pytorch clears the computation graph after one backwards pass, triggering this error. You can force it to keep the graph with `loss.backward(retain_graph = True)`

Comment: Sure, however in my case, each iteration has loss forward pass followed by the backward pass, so the graph is always calculated before it is released.